# If I set up as self employed, will my current employer be notified of this?

Tags: uk, local-business

I’m just in the process of [setting up as a sole trader](http://www.smarta.com/advice/starting-up/starting-your-own-business/what-is-a-sole-trader/)[,](https://moneybanker.com/) alongside my current employment and was wondering about a **few things.**

If I set up as self employed, will my current employer be notified of this?

The industries are completely different and it doesn’t state in my contract I can have other employment but just wondered if they will find out?

Comment: I am assuming UK (based on your link). Please tag your country

Comment: Yes, add your country for any meaningful replies. But in the EU your employer will not be notified: why would they have the right to receive such information?

Comment: They may be able to tell you are receiving another income from your tax code, but they won't know why.

Answer (score 2):

> If I set up as self employed, will my current employer be notified of
>   this?

No. You might have a change in tax code from HMRC, but your employer has no right to question it.

> The industries are completely different and it doesn’t state in my
>   contract I can have other employment but just wondered if they will
>   find out?

Probably not, but it's a good idea to tell them anyway just in case a conflict of interest arises down the line

A couple of extra tips:

- Record your expenses from day one. Do it daily.
- Use a decent accountant for if you go Ltd company, I use Quba
- Put 20% of your takings to one side for corporation tax before paying yourself (if Ltd), then put 20% of what you pay yourself to one side for personal tax

Source: Currently a Ltd Company Cotractor and former HMRC Revenue Officer and Taxation Adviser